Which of the following answers for an error analysis problem is correct?
The problem goes: I have a Sharp GP2D120 analog infrared distance sensor that follows the calibration equation:
$$d = 0.1594 * V^{(-0.8533)} - 0.02916$$
where d is distance in meters and V is output voltage. Within the range $0.04 m ≤ d ≤ 0.30 m$, I've taken multiple measurements of a stationary target and obtained a voltage reading of $0.8 ± 0.15 V$.
Now the problem lies in how to estimate the error in this measurement, the general equation for estimating error propagation that I know of for any $Q = q(x)$, is
$$ \delta Q = \biggl|\frac{dq}{dx}\biggr|\delta x$$
which is derived from the first-order expansion of Taylor's Polynomials and the \delta stands for error. Explanation for this equation can be found in: https://cdn.serc.carleton.edu/files/nagt/jge/columns/CG16-v49n3p305.pdf
I have two solutions here. I'm actually having a debate over which of the following answers is right, so I would appreciate any answer telling me this. The question may actually be simple for anyone familiar with this, but I just need some third-party verification. Thanks for your guys' time and efforts in advance!
Calculation details for the result that is 0.03
Calculation details for the result that is 0.004
BTW, here is a clue on the estimation formulas for error propagation with independent random uncertainties, essentially from a class slide:
formulas. For the formulas in the slide, one could try to verify that the formula for power functions is essentially derived from the formula for general functions. The process is fairly simple and I can provide it myself if required.

What happens when you calculate $\frac{dq}{dx}$ with both possibilities for $q(x)$?

Well, the 2 possibilities lead to different estimations for propagated error, one is 0.004, the other is 0.03, both after rounding.

@SeanZu that seems wrong, can you show the calculation in detail?

@user619894 Which answer are you referring to that seems wrong?

@user619894 Hi buddy, I have added the calculation details above, could you please take a look?

$d+c_0=a_0 V^{b_0}$ then $\ln(d+c_0) = \ln a_0 + b_0\ln V$ and $\frac{\delta d}{d+c_0} = b_0\frac{\delta V}{V}$

@Cesareo Could you please elaborate or give me any reference on how the last step deriving $\frac{\delta d}{d+c_0} = b_0\frac{\delta V}{V}$ is done? And which answer I listed above do you think is right? Thanks.

It doesn't matter which of the two assumptions you use. Constant terms will cancel anyway, since the error propagation only depends on the derivative of your quantity, which doesn't depend on constant terms.
It's your second calculation that's wrong. First of all, I urge you to stick to a sensible starting point. If you want to calculate absolute errors, don't use formulae for relative errors ($\frac{\delta Q}{Q}$). That aside, you need to calculate $\frac{\partial d(V)}{\partial V}$, which, for $d=aV^n+b$, is $anV^{n-1}$, and you forgot the factor $V^{n-1}$ in the second calculation.
